# 960gs nested grid in combination with responsive

Tags: html

Good evening everyone,

I had a question about using nested grid of 960.gs and responsive webdesign.
Currently I use nested grid and the classes Alpha and Omega, to the left (alpha) and right (omega) margins to reset to 0. This is now hardcoded.
The structure of my grid is as follows:

```
 <div class="grid_8">
  <ul class="recentbox">

       <li class="grid_4 projectbox alpha">
            <a href="#">

            <div class="thumbnails">
               <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnails/thumbnail-5.png" alt="Thumbnail">
            </div> <! - End. Thumbnails ->
            </a>

            <div class="description">
                 <h3> <a href="#"> Title Project </a> </h3>
                 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit consectetur adipiscing. Phasellus ante quis eros.
                 </p>
            </div> <! - End. Description ->

            <div class="tags">
                Tags: Photoshop, Illustrator, Graphic Design
            </div> <! - End. Tags ->
        </li> <! - End li.grid_4 projectbox ->



       <li class="grid_4 projectbox">
            <a href="#">

            <div class="thumbnails">
               <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnails/thumbnail-5.png" alt="Thumbnail">
            </div> <! - End. Thumbnails ->
            </a>

            <div class="description">
                 <h3> <a href="#"> Title Project </a> </h3>
                 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit consectetur adipiscing. Phasellus ante quis eros.
                 </p>
            </div> <! - End. Description ->

            <div class="tags">
                Tags: Photoshop, Illustrator, Graphic Design
            </div> <! - End. Tags ->
        </li> <! - End li.grid_4 projectbox ->



       <li class="grid_4 projectbox omega">
            <a href="#">

            <div class="thumbnails">
               <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnails/thumbnail-5.png" alt="Thumbnail">
            </div> <! - End. Thumbnails ->
            </a>

            <div class="description">
                 <h3> <a href="#"> Title Project </a> </h3>
                 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit consectetur adipiscing. Phasellus ante quis eros.
                 </p>
            </div> <! - End. Description ->

            <div class="tags">
                Tags: Photoshop, Illustrator, Graphic Design
            </div> <! - End. Tags ->
        </li> <! - End li.grid_4 projectbox ->

   </ul> <! - End ul ->
```

My website has a 3 column layout.
What is now the problem is that I want to make my website responsive. For my iPad I design instead of 3 columns only 2. When I make my container the proper width (for iPad), the last div (with the extra class omega) at the bottom of the first div to stand, making this div the wrong property. Fully Sighted classes alpha and omega are hardcoded in code, changed not take them. The middle div in the example above would actually have to get the omega class and the last div (which is now under the first condition), the alpha class should get.

I want the site with responsive media queries and my question is, how do I do to, to alpha and omega to be able to adapt to the grid or how I go about doing this without classes to?

Thank you already!

Greetz, Casper B

PS: Sorry for my English it's not my mother tongue.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your html is very badly formatted, can you fix that?

Comment: @nycynik Hope this is better for you. So we can talk about it and find an possible solution!